# Angular 17 SSR: Module '"@angular/ssr"' has no exported member 'REQUEST'

Tags: angular, angular-ssr

I'm trying to get cookies on Angular 17 with SSR, in the past there was the `REQUEST` pulled from `@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens`, but since @angular/ssr I don't find where to pull REQUEST from

```
import { REQUEST } from '@angular/ssr'; // Module '"@angular/ssr"' has no exported member 'REQUEST'.
```

Or maybe there is a new way to fetch cookies.

The main thing I need is the Bearer token to add it to the header request, if there is a better way to do this, then I would be interested! (the API is on another URL, so using cookies directly wouldn't work well due to CORS).

EDIT:
After some research, I found

```
const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
```

and I've added `{ provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req }` to the server.ts, which looks like

```
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
          { provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req },
        ],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
```

and finally `constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request)`, but this returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right track, but I wasn't doing it the proper way. If someone is interested here is what works.

Add `APP_SSR_COOKIES` on `server.ts`

```
server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

  commonEngine
    .render({
      bootstrap,
      documentFilePath: indexHtml,
      url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
      publicPath: browserDistFolder,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
        { provide: APP_SSR_COOKIES, useValue: req.headers.cookie },
      ],
    })
    .then((html) => res.send(html))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

On your `cookie.service.ts`

```
// this const is loaded on the server.ts
export const APP_SSR_COOKIES = new InjectionToken<any>('APP_SSR_COOKIES');

export class CookieService {
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string,
    @Optional() @Inject(APP_SSR_COOKIES) private ssrCookies: string
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
  }

  check(name: string): boolean {
    const regExp = this.getRegExp(name);
    return regExp.test(this.isBrowser ? this.doc.cookie : this.ssrCookies);
  }
}
```

Comment: do we need an interceptor here? @Shadoweb

Comment: @NFard not here no, the full code is above.

Comment: thanks, and how you send cookies to server on first request? @Shadoweb

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26323) on the CLI repo. The dev-server does not rely on the express server.

So the providers aren't set when in dev.

Comment: OK, that replies to 1 of my question, but it doesn't work even with the Live having `{ provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req }` in the provider on server.ts. I've edited my question.

Comment: Currently `server.ts` is not used by the devServer.

Comment: So you mean it works out of the box on prod build? 
I mean cookies are attached to requests automatically?